# shifting partial datetimeindex by 1 hour pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with hourly values during the workweek:

```
>>> vol_adjust.head()
Out[59]: 
2011-11-01 05:00:00+11:00   3237454603.000
2011-11-01 06:00:00+11:00   3292278695.000
2011-11-01 07:00:00+11:00   6037960826.000
2011-11-01 08:00:00+11:00   7127161746.000
2011-11-01 09:00:00+11:00   3382477744.000

>>> vol_adjust.shape
Out[60]: (29658, 1)
```

The problem is that some of the values fall on saturdays- generally only 1 value. I have 5 such dates in the whole dataframe:

```
>>> vol_adjust[vol_adjust.index.dayofweek == 5]
Out[63]: 
2012-03-03 00:00:00+11:00    794977434.400
2012-03-17 00:00:00+11:00    403171073.800
2013-03-16 00:00:00+11:00    808805223.800
2014-03-15 00:00:00+11:00   1622434962.000
2016-03-05 00:00:00+11:00    569319700.900
Name: vol, dtype: float64
```

Upon inspection, it seems that on some day during the week, the data skips the 00:00 AM entry(midnight) e.g.

```
>>> vol_adjust['2012-03-01'].tail()
Out[75]: 
2012-03-01 19:00:00+11:00    931207673.400
2012-03-01 20:00:00+11:00   2213366040.000
2012-03-01 21:00:00+11:00    994524108.700
2012-03-01 22:00:00+11:00    541624218.800
2012-03-01 23:00:00+11:00   2085975988.000
Name: vol, dtype: float64
>>> vol_adjust['2012-03-02'].head()
Out[70]: 
2012-03-02 01:00:00+11:00   1951010063.000
2012-03-02 02:00:00+11:00   1703256493.000
2012-03-02 03:00:00+11:00    947991961.000
2012-03-02 04:00:00+11:00   1210964133.000
2012-03-02 05:00:00+11:00    908680999.300
Name: vol, dtype: float64
```

I have a way of identifying such dates, and would like to move the hours up by 1 from the start of troubled day to the corresponding Saturday. Is there a simple way of doing this? e.g. lets say I knew  '2012-03-02' to '2012-03-03' is the period where the index is off by 1 hour, how can I shift it up by 1 hr easily only for that time while keeping the rest unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` over an index and use a `lambda` function. See:

```
vol_adjust.index = vol_adjust.index.map(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta(1, 'h') if str(x.date()) in trouble_days else x)
```

That is assuming that `trouble_days` are in the form of strings `'2012-02-03'` otherwise you can do not need the `str(x.date())` conversion.

Note that this would shift by 1h all the hours of the days in `troubled_days` which would create 23 samples for the each of those days and 25 samples for the day after the troubled day, since 00:00 would become 01:00 of the next day and the index entry would be repeated - I guess you don't want that. But this you can sort it out with a bit more complex logic in the lambda function.